# doctrine,application level cascade: [delete] does not work

Tags: php, doctrine-1.2

i am using doctrine's SoftDelete and upon deletion i would like to SofDelete the related records.

here is the Schema file i am using.

```
detect_relations: true
User:
  actAs:
    Timestampable:
    SoftDelete:
    Sluggable:
      unique: true
      fields: [name]
      canUpdate: true
  tableName: user
  columns:
    name:
      type: string(50)
      notnull: true
    email:
      type: string(50)
      notnull: true
      unique: true
    password:
      type: string(50)
      notnull: true
    business_id: integer
  relations:
    Business:
      cascade: [delete]
Business:
  actAs:
    Timestampable:
    SoftDelete:
    Sluggable:
      unique: true
      fields: [name]
      canUpdate: true
  tableName: business
  columns:
    name:
      type: string(50)
      notnull: true
    website: string(100)
    address: string(100)
```

when i try to SoftDelete user it does not delete related record from business table (i.e it does not update the `deleted_at` flag in the business table). only the `deleted_at` flag from the user table is updated.

the DQL i am using is.

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->delete('Model_User u')
    ->where('u.id = ?', $id);
$q ->execute();
```

where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching around for some time, i finally found the solution by myself. hope this helps someone with the same problem as mine.

here are few of the conditions for application level delete cascade to work.

- **Unlike the save() operations the delete() cascading needs to be turned on explicitly**

apart from defining `cascade: [delete]` in your Schema, it is important to note that you need to explicitly define the relations too. 
if you are depending on `detect_relations: true` for you to generate all the relations this won't work for application level delete cascade. (atleast it didn't work for me, after manually defining the relations it worked though).

- **Application level cascading save() and delete() does not apply when doing DQL update and delete statements, only when calling save() and
  delete() on your objects.**

doctrine documentation is not clear about this. i had to refer symfony documentation for this to understand. doctrine documentation only says.

> The following describes the generic procedure when you delete a record
>   through **$record->delete()**:

for me to understand it was quite confusing. but after going through symfony's documentation of doctrine i was clear about how to do it. so instead of deleting through DQL. i had to use this.

```
$user = Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')->find(1)
$user->delete();
```

and Booom, it works. :)

P.S: here is the link to symfony documentation in case if anyone wants to refer.

http://www.symfony-project.org/doctrine/1_2/en/04-Schema-Files#chapter_04_sub_application_level

and here is the link to a post which clarifies my doubt which is not of any use though :)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/doctrine-user/POq6ybO01lg%5B1-25%5D